# Chartkick gem "no block given" runtime error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, shopify-app, chartkick

I'm currently trying to display a chart showing the revenue from a shopify boutique, hour by hour. So I came with this :

In my controller I have this, which returns a JSON:

```
@orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all)
```

And in my view I have this:

```
<%= line_chart @orders.group_by_hour_of_day(:created_at).count, xtitle: "Hour of the day", ytitle: "Profit in AED" %>
```

Then when trying to launch it locally I have a "no block given error".
I've been searching for 2 days if it's not a syntax error can't find anything.

I also tried just by showing `<%= line_chart @orders %>` and I have an empty chart. So I guest my issue is when I try to fetch a value from the JSON.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is `@orders`  empty?

Comment: What's `group_by_hour_of_day` method? Where does it come from? I guess it requires a block to be passed and that's why you get this error.

Comment: It's possible you actually wanted to have `@orders.group_by_hour_of_day(&:created_at)`, which is equivalent to `@orders.group_by_hour_of_day { |o| o.created_at }`, but it's only guess.

Comment: @MarekLipka Indeed, just tried and the error is gone, but show an empty graph. However, when I try to add the sum of all orders, with or without the & :
`<%= line_chart orders.group_by_hour_of_day(&:created_at).sum(:total_price), xtitle: "Hour of the day", ytitle: "Profit in AED" %>`

it return an error : undefined method `+' for :total_price:Symbol